# Set Activity Toolbar Behavior from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an application that opens to an `Activity' hosting a`Fragment.`

The `Fragment` displays a `RecyclerView`, and users can click on an item within the `RecyclerView` to be taken to a new `Fragment`, hosted by the same `Activity`.

The `Toolbar` xml item is located within th `Activity`, not each individual `Fragment`. When the user navigates to the second `Fragment`, I want them to be able to click the back button to navigate back to the previous `Fragment`.

Below is the code navigating from `Fragment` to `Fragment`:

```
holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String pollID = mFireAdapter.getRef(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();
                    Fragment pollFragment = PollFragment.newInstance(pollID);
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
                    ft.add(R.id.poll_feed_fragment, pollFragment);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
```

In the next `Fragment`, I want to show the back button and am trying to do so by accessing the `.setDisplayHomeUpAsEnabled()` method to no avail:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poll, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(v);

    Toolbar toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.action_tool_bar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your fragment your can use method getActivity.

```
((Your_activity_class_name)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
```

Then create custom method which will return your toolbar. Or if you set toolbar like support action bar via method [setSupportActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up) just use [getSupportActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity#getsupportactionbar)

Your do not need each time find your toolbar, cause you already did it.